# Using IBM blockchain platform extension in VSCode using command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

My VsCode editor is installed on a linux machine(Ubuntu 18)
I have been using IBM blockchain platform extension in vs code to start local Hyperledger fabric environment.
However i would like to start local hyperledger fabric environment using command line so that i can automate this as a shell script.
Can anyone guide me as how to start Local hyperledger fabric environment using command line on Microsoft VSCode editor installed on a linux machine.